How to read the OS81050 chip
I have a board which is faulty and need to read a OS81050 chip but I was wondering if anyone knows what device and how to read the chip OS81050?
This chip has been diagnosed as faulty so I need to read it and program new one and I need go on how to read it?
Full part number is OS81050AH
I want to read the faulty chip to program new one for a amplifier on a car

I was wondering if anyone knows ... is not a question about an electronics problem ... please ask about the problem ... this site is not a chat forum... do not use chat language ... submit a complete question about the problem you are trying to solve

Ok thanks, what kind of device can read it and program new one

Can you clarify if you either (a) Are looking to buy an off-the-shelf programmer for a OS81050 - which is a shopping question and off-topic (b) Advice on how to design your own programmer which is on-topic but will require more detail on what help you need.

Can you also clarify if (a) You have a faulty OS81050 are you expecting to read the flash / OPT from the faulty OS81050 (b) Or you have a working OS81050 on a different board, which want to clone the contents of

does the board read the chip or something else

Hi I have a faulty os81050 and want to read it and program new one, so the board will be the same and just want to see if it’s possible to read faulty chip to clone it onto new one

There’s not much info about this chip so I don’t really know what to do next, I need some help on how I can read this faulty chip and program new one, if making a device is possible I don’t mind but I honestly don’t know how to read this chip

It's a Microchip somewhat-special part. An integrated intelligence network controller for the MOST network.
Product page
Short-form Data sheet
Microchip library for programming via I squared c   here
Data sheet claimed here may or may not be + here

Ok thanks, what kind of device can read it and program new one ?

@ImranAli Read the microchip library link. Programming is done via an  I squared c interface.

Fancy that. A downvote Christmas present. I'll not mention the Grinch

-1. Wow. Not the first in the past few days. It appears somebody may have an agenda. So it goes.
